# Does this distribution exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Consider the following summation:

$$\sum_{n,d} \frac{δ\left(t - \tfrac{n}{d}\right)}{(nd)^σ}$$

Where $δ(t)$ is the Dirac delta distribution, and $σ$ is a constant, and $n,d>0$.

Every partial sum exists. It is easy to come up with a sequence whose limit would be the infinite summation I want over all n,d. But does the limit actually exist as a distribution, at least for some choice of σ?

Furthermore, supposing it exists, does the integral of this distribution exist? If so, is there any expression for it?

I came up with this while messing around with the zeta function, and hit a sticking point here.

Comment: In what sense do you want your integral? If your sum is a distributions, then it has an antiderivative. However, this antiderivative is not necessarily an "easy-to-write-explicitly" function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a test function $\phi$ with support in $[-R,R]$. Then your operator applied to $\phi$ becomes

$$\sum _{n,d}\frac{\phi(n/d)}{(nd)^\sigma}\le \|\phi\|_{\infty}\sum_{n,d:1\le n\le Rd}\frac{1}{(nd)^\sigma}.$$

It easy to check that the sum $\sum_{n,d:1\le n\le Rd}\frac{1}{(nd)^\sigma}$ is finite for $\sigma>1$. Hence, by definition, your operator is a distribution of order zero.

Comment: That's a great argument. So to confirm I understand properly, we consider distributions to be continuous linear operators $L_\infty \to \Bbb R$, and since they're continuous they're also bounded. Actually, it looks like you're working the other way with it above - you're saying my distribution, which I'll call $\Delta$, is also a continuous linear operator on the space of test functions, which also happens to be a subspace of $L_\infty$. So $\frac{|\langle \Delta, \phi \rangle |}{\|\Delta\|_1} \leq \| \phi \|_\infty$. Is that right?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia We can't really define $\Delta$ on $L_\infty$, because we do not have the point values of functions in this space (since these functions are defined "up to a set of measure zero"). We showed that $\Delta$ is well-defined on $C_c(\Bbb R)$, which is a subspace of $D'(\Bbb R)$. After that you get the order of $\Delta$ (it is equal to zero, because we don't derivatives to estimate $\langle\Delta,\phi\rangle$); moreover, one can try to show that $\Delta$ is a tempered distribution.

Comment: Sorry, what is C_c and D'? Just starting out here and still a bit unfamiliar with the notation. Also, I think a better way of saying what I was trying to say is that every test function is bounded, so you know the application of the distribution to the test function is less than or equal to the application of the distribution to a constant function of the same support, which you can also use to show it's a tempered distribution. Right?

Comment: $C_c$ is a set of continuous functions with compact support. $D$ is a set of test functions ($C_c^\infty$ - compactly supported, infinitely derivable). $D'$ is a space of distributions.

Comment: Ok. But my distribution *is* defined on the subspace of $L_\infty$ consisting of smooth functions. Right? Because none of them can differ from another by a set of measure zero.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia yes, if you put it this way.